# How to get back one folder path url using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get one back folder path from the url.But not working.I do not know how to get the path?

I expected url name like http://localhost/testing/ from http://localhost/testing/flower/

Example:

```
const path = require('path');

var url = http://localhost/testing/flower/

var reqPath = path.join(url, './');

console.log( reqPath );
```

Comment: `./` is current, not back.

Comment: this is an issue that doesn't need its own module. Just remove the last `/`if it exists then substring from start until last occurence of `/`. Add som handling of root path on that an you're golden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go up a directory you use `../`

```
const path = require('path');

var url = http://localhost/testing/flower/

var reqPath = path.join(url, '../');

console.log( reqPath );
```

Comment: @charlietfl its is a valid call, i recommend looking up documentation for path https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend simple manual parsing of the string

```js
function goUp(url){
  if (url.endsWith("/")) url = url.substring(0,url.length-1)
  const lastSlashPosition = url.lastIndexOf("/"); 

  return lastSlashPosition <=7 ? url: url.substring(0,lastSlashPosition);
}


console.log(goUp("http://localhost/"));
console.log(goUp("http://localhost/testing/flower"));
console.log(goUp("http://localhost/testing/flower/"));
```

Comment: Make sure to check for urls ending with a slash and check that the url isn't allready at the top